# How can I save "response.body().string()" to String variable?

Tags: java, response, okhttp

I don't understand why I can't do it:

```
String accept = response.body().string();
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed

Part of code:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
response.newBuilder();
```

It's typical issue for "OkHttpClient".

Comment: Can you add your existing code? okhttp's sample code which is here http://square.github.io/okhttp/ should work fine.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! Your link was help me.
But i don't know why 
`System.out.println(response.body().string());`
doesn't work now. But it's not important. Thank you again ))

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it by creating passing in a new Callback object the:

```
@Override
    public void retrieveEvents(String username) {
        service.getEvents(username).enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Event>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Event>> call, Response<ArrayList<Event>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    view.updateEventsView(response.body());
                    view.setFetching(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Event>> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                view.updateEventsView(new ArrayList<Event>());
                view.setFetching(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

So in your case, you could set a the response's body to the string value.